# Where can I find an overview of global visa policy changes in a given year?

Tags: visas

As an example, Iran [liberalised their visa policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Iran) considerably in the past few years, but unless you follow them closely you would never find out about this change. Likewise India introduced an e-visa a few years ago, which made travel there a lot easier.

Is there a website or some other resource where I can find out about changes to visa policies in a given year? This would let me plan my travels according to what regions are newly accessible without applying for a visa.

Comment: I think if you narrow it down to a certain nationality i.e. a US citizen can use [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_United_States_citizens) and a Canadian citizen can use [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Canadian_citizens) is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Newton I don't see a list of visa policy changes for 2017 there

Comment: 'Visa requirements amendment log' is at the bottom of the page

Comment: my bad it's there for Canadians but not for Americans

Comment: @Newton I think that's the best option so far, feel free to add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the IATA Travel Centre: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/

It is a free service by the International Air Transport Association (290 airlines) who need to maintain accurate visa, health and regulations information.

You just need to complete a form entering the particular parameters of your trip (destination, origin, your nationality etc) and then you get an instant reply.

Wikipedia also has some relevant information on recent and planned Visa changes, in pages titled "Visa policy of XYZ" 
for example see: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_States
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_Kingdom  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area

Comment: That's a great resource for checking visa requirements, but it's not the source for visa *changes* that the OP is looking for.

Comment: This is correct. Perhaps Wikipedia then, for example this article includes a section on Policy Changes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area

Comment: @AntonisP worth updating your answer ,not putting useful info in comments where it may be missed.